# codelite C++ compilation issue

Tags: c++

I am  using Codelite on windows 64 bit and am getting the following message as below

[image: Compilation error]

I am adding the following linker libraries which is external as below in codelite as below
[image: Linker in Codelite]

Following is the simple code I have written as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tc/emh.h>
#include <tc/tc.h>
#include <tc/tc_startup.h>
#include <tccore/aom.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <base_utils/IFail.hxx>
#include <base_utils/TcResultStatus.hxx>
#include <metaframework/BusinessObjectRegistry.hxx>
#include <metaframework/CreateInput.hxx>
#include <mld/logging/TcMainLogger.hxx>
#include <tccore/Item.hxx>

using namespace std;
using namespace Teamcenter;
using Teamcenter::Main::logger;

int ITK_user_main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
  
    cout<<"This is a test "<<endl;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

When I am compiling I am getting the following message as below.

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C
> D:/Programs/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -j4 SHELL=cmd.exe
> -e -f  Makefile "----------Building project:[ Test - Debug ]----------" mingw32-make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHqUG.png): Entering directory
> 'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Documents/Test'
> D:/Programs/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe -o Debug/Test @"Test.txt"
> -L. -LD:\Siemens\TC12\TC_ROOT\lib  -litk_main.obj D:/Programs/mingw-w64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
> cannot find -litk_main.obj collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit
> status mingw32-make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHqUG.png): *** [Test.mk:81: Debug/Test] Error 1
> mingw32-make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHqUG.png): Leaving directory
> 'C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/Documents/Test' mingw32-make.exe:
> *** [Makefile:5: All] Error 2
> ====0 errors, 0 warnings====

Is there something that I am missing that the obj files are not found....

Comment: I am using CODELITE as IDE on windows...

Comment: Please copy error messages, don't post pictures. I cant' read the error message, and therefore I can't help answer the question. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should really make use of a build system here...
I can recommend cmake, it will make your life a lot easier!
The following two lines will do the linking and package finding for you

`find_package(ITK REQUIRED)
link_libraries(ITKCommon)`

Cmake is definitely worth to take a look at, CodeLite even has built-in support for it!

Comment: I am using Windows. Will cmake work on windows. If there are any pointers to build a cmake project on windows

Comment: Of course. Cmake projects are very portable between different platforms. You should go to their tutorial site: https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/. There is even a GUI application to run Cmake without having to write it by hand.